# Direct connection to Firebird with IBDac/UniDac from Android using Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, unidac, firebird-3.0

I'm trying to connect to a REMOTE Firebird Database from Android using Delphi and IBDac. It says that cannot find libfbclient.so.3.0.2 library. I put it in the deploy to all library paths and nothing. If I remove the library it doesn't connect neither. The android version is 7.0. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If IBDac is similar to JDBC or ODBC then this SO post may be appropriate: [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004)

Comment: What do you mean "to all library paths"? Have you tried deploying it to the same path as the app? (i.e. a Remote Path of just .\)

Comment: All library paths in Delphi -> Android are library\lib\armeabi-v7a\ library\lib\armeabi\ library\lib\mips\ maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

**in `delphi` (deploying):** add file libfbclient.so.3.0.2

remote-path: assets\internal

**in delphi (program):**

no entry in IBCConnection ClientLibrary

source code:

```
IBCConnection1.Server:= *server-ip or name*;
IBCConnection1.ClientLibrary:= TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'libfbclient.so.3.0.2');
IBCConnection1.DataBase:= *datebase name*;
IBCConnection1.Connect;
```